# How to write formula field to replace multiple values in the field?

Tags: apex, trigger, formula, formula-field

I have a field with the value 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8
I would like to replace with one;two;three;four;five;six;seven;eight through formula field.

Workaround:
**Used Substitute function:**

```
SUBSTITUTE(Name, "1", "One" )& 
SUBSTITUTE(Name, "2", "Two" )
```

> Value in Name: 1;2
>
> Value from Formula Field:One;21;Two

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `SUBSTITUTE` in a nested fashion like this:

```
SUBSTITUTE(
    SUBSTITUTE(
        SUBSTITUTE(
            SUBSTITUTE(
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    SUBSTITUTE(
                        SUBSTITUTE(
                            SUBSTITUTE(
                                SUBSTITUTE(Name
                                , "1", "One" )
                            , "2", "Two")
                        , "3", "Three")
                    , "4", "Four")
                , "5", "Five" )
            , "6", "Six" )
        , "7", "Seven" )
    , "8", "Eight" )
, "9", "Nine" )
```

So that you will be passing the result of the inner one to the outer one. If you use `&` that will append the values.